# Planting too many seeds in small pot

Tags: indoors, germination, seedlings, basil, overseeding

What will happen if i keep my sweet basil here?

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Your plants will have to compete with each other for light, and root space. Because they are so packed and crowded, none of the plants will grow optimal this way. If you just want basil cress, you can harvest already, but if you want real and healthy basil plants you need to trim (or pull) away most of it. I think you have to leave 1-2 cm between plants at minimum.

Comment: Tiny scissors are helpful at this point. If you pull the extras, you'll lose a lot of dirt.

Answer (score 1):

Ummmm, are you asking about that center pot?  Your donut shaped plants should be transplanted into 6" pots with potting soil only.  Dump the whole pot and donut out of the main pot, using serrated knife, carve a chunk about an inch wide of that donut, and put in its new pot. Lightly plant the roots in the new potting soil, add (balanced fertilizer) give plenty of light.  You'll have 7 or 8 pots worth of basil (not every single plant will live from the chunks you cut off) but just one plant per pot will give you a beautiful full basil plant.  What type of basil is this???  Why the donut thing?  Next time you buy seed make sure you get NON GMO and you have try THAI basil!!  I use this basil for everything I want basil into...

If you wanted, you should pull that center pot out, fill with potting soil then then with tweezers until you get 6 viable plants left.  This is a worthy solution if you have used only potting soil.

Comment: Basil is pretty hardy to being transplanted. I've pulled plants/roots out of pots nearly as crowded as the above pix. Bare roots. Planted them outside, and they grew into beautiful 2.5 foot plants; gallons of pesto.  Be aware that Robins love to eat Basil cotyledons, so you'll want to wait fof secondary leaves.

Answer (score 0):

If we plant too many seeds in a small pot the plant wouldn’t be huge it will remain small, because of this we should plant seeds in a big pot.